# GWT: No source code available for type java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: gwt

[image]I have a class in my shared package which have this ByteArrayOutputStream
But still getting this exception.

Any idea whats the reason and what could be the solution

```
           No source code is available for type java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module
```

My xml class

```
             <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
              <source path='client'/>
                    <source path='shared'/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to use `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` on the GWT client side, which gets compiled out into javascript. Because of this, only a subset of the java classes are supported for use on the client side.

To see which classes are supported on the client side, see here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

Comment: How can i use it on server side , I try to move that class to server package , shared package, but it still gives error..

Comment: @junaidp GWT will try to compile any directory that you declare with a `<source path='...' />` tag for use in the client side. Place the class on the server package, and make sure you don't have a `<source path='server'/>` declaration.

Comment: Hi , Nop .. Please have a look on the attached screenshot .. please suggest.  Thanks

Comment: @junaidp now you are having a different problem. You are calling the server side class `Comparator` from the client side. If you want to use `Comparator` in both client and server sides, place it in the `shared` package. Did I resolve your original issue?

Comment: previously it was in shared .. No source code is available for type java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream......... This error was coming from shared folder ..but shared is defined in my xml class , If i remove shared from there it will give errors on my other class in shared

Comment: @junaidp ok, I understand the problem now. Like I said originally, `ByteArrayOutputStream` is only usable on the server side. Therefore, you have to place `Comparator` on the server side. If you want to use a method in `Comparator` on the client side, you must use make a RPC call with an `AsyncCallback`. There's no other way to use `ByteArrayOutputStream` directly on the client side.